Identify a Murder Mystery Movie with Detectives
I am trying to identify a movie that is plotted similar to Agatha Christies "And Then There Were None".  The difference is that all the people invited are detectives, including one from Scotland Yard (I think) and China (stereotype wardrobe and hair).
Guessing the movie is from the 50's but not certain.  I remember it being in color.  One scene is the classic setting in the dining room, but instead the Chinese detective stands, or asks another to stand, just as something falls onto the chair or a dart is shot into the chair, preventing them from dying. The plot proceeds with them attempting to figure out who is trying to kill them all.

Believe you are looking for Murder by Death (1976), which is a send up of murder mysteries.
All the guests are knock-offs of famous fictional detectives: 

Sam Diamond (Sam Spade)
Jessica Marbles (Miss Marple)
Dick and Dora Charleston (Nick and Nora Charles)
Sidney Wang (Charlie Chan)
Milo Perrier (Hercule Poirot)

The chair scene is when Dick Charleston realizes everyone has been seated incorrectly according to etiquette. 

omg i never realized it was a parody, remember watching this as a little kid.  thanks!

You're welcome. One of my favorites.
